# Base64 decoding github api readme Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, github-api

What I want to do:
grab the base64 readme.md contents of the **github API**. F.e. https://api.github.com/repos/airbnb/lottie-ios/contents/README.md

In my ruby application **decode** **the base64**, this should returns markdown. This markdown I can parse to HTML to be used on my site.

```
require 'commonmarker'
require "base64"
require 'logger'

class ToolsController < ApplicationController
    impressionist :actions=>[:show]

    def show
        log = Logger.new('log.txt')
        @tool = Tool.friendly.where.not("status ~* ?", "(Scheduled|Draft)").find(params[:id])
        impressionist(@tool)
        @related_tools = @tool.categories.first.tools.published.where.not(id: @tool.id).sample(3)
        encoded_string = File.read("test-tool-readme.txt")
        decoded_string = Base64.decode64(encoded_string)
        log.debug(decoded_string) # EMPTY 
        @tool_test_markdown_body = CommonMarker.render_doc(decoded_string, :DEFAULT).to_plaintext
        render "show-with-github"
    end
end
```

For some reason it will not decode the base64... online tools or local tools seem to do it perfectly. It returns null. In strict mode it fails.

Does anyone know why I can't decode this base64?

Comment: The snippet you shared has only one invocation of `Base64.decode64`, and it's on the contents of a file. Would you like to make that file available to us? Likely when the data was saved to that file, it was not saved correctly.

Comment: @JellicleCat atm nothing has been deployed, this is just locally created. If I log "encoded_string" it shows the content of the file. The file itself is just a txt file with the base64 string.

Comment: Okay, but if it 'will not decode the base64', that suggests that the content of your file is bad. Does it end with a trailing newline character?